# CKBrowseSwitcherViewController override the -traitcollection getter?

Tags: ios, swift, codesign, uitraitcollection

> 2020-11-17 15:56:01.464383-0800 LibraryTally[24499:8154415]
>
> [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the
> -traitCollection getter,  which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.

[image]

So recently I get to run an app I built before the Xcode12.2 upgrade, and these two things pop up. I've solved the "CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" with some research, but i wonder why these "traitCollection not supported" and "CodeSign failed" things will show up? Are they related? and Is that due to the upgrade?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter... What this message means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58779786/class-ckbrowserswitcherviewcontroller-overrides-the-traitcollection-getter-w)

Answer (score 1):

I can't verify this, but someone said that per iOS 12 Beta 2 release notes:

> When running your app from Xcode, you might see console errors about UIKit classes that override the traitCollection getter. You can safely ignore these messages for system classes. If you see this error message for your own classes, it likely indicates a real issue for you to fix. (51651561)